# Rails 3: has_and_belongs_to_many relationship being created, but can't be retrieved

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activerecord

**The short version:**

I have a Rails 3.2.1.4 unit test that is trying to create a new many-to-many relationship in an external database. The relationship is created, but I cannot get ActiveRecord to retrieve it.

**The long version:**

I have a Rails 3.2.1.4 project that is interacting with an external MySQL database that has two tables that have a many-to-many relationship via the conventional join table.

I have a test that creates a new relationship on existing data but can't retrieve the relationship. Here's the failing test:

```
class ExternalTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @foo_id = 1
    @foo = ExternalAsset.find(@foo_id)
  end

  test "subjects attach correctly"
    @foo.external_subjects << ExternalSubject.find(2)
    assert_equal 1, ExternalAsset.find(@foo_id).external_subjects.count
  end
end
```

To add to the frustration, adding and querying back the many-to-many relationship with almost this exact code works just fine in the console.

I have googled the living heck out of this and come up empty. My best guess is that this is some sort of freak interaction of ActiveRecord, an external database connection, and the test framework.

Here's the models I'm dealing with:

```
class ExternalAsset < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "external_#{Rails.env}"

  self.table_name = :assets

  has_and_belongs_to_many :external_subjects, :join_table => :assets_subjects, 
    :association_foreign_key => :subject_id, :foreign_key => :asset_id
end

class ExternalSubject < ActiveRecord::Base

  establish_connection "external_#{Rails.env}"

  self.table_name = :subjects

  has_and_belongs_to_many :external_assets, :join_table => :assets_subjects, 
    :association_foreign_key => :asset_id, :foreign_key => :subject_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you use static IDs in your test, try to [use fixtures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) for instance.

Some remarks: You don't clearly state your issue, and your question is really too long, you should sum up your issue in a few lines in one code example.

Comment: Any tips for cleaning up the question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: abeger: try to reduce the code examples to the minimum and explain clearly your issue